# SQL to get count of distinct rows based on different rules

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

Say you have a table like:

```
| key | status |
| --- | ------ |
| 3   | A      |
| 4   | A      |
| 4   | C      |
| 5   | B      |
| 6   | B      |
| 6   | C      |
| 7   | A      |
| 7   | B      |
```

I want a query that returns, in a single row, the count of the number of rows that contain a specific `status`, but applying some priority rules. The rules would be different for each row and something like:

- Column `a_count` = count of any distinct `key` that has a status of `A`
- Column `b_count` = count of any distinct `key` that has a status of `B`, but where the same key does not also appear with a status of `A`
- Column `c_count` = count of any distinct `key` that has a status of `C`, but where the same key does not also appear with a status of `A` or `B`

The point being that the total of all counts should equal the total number of distinct keys in the source table. In my sample data above, the results should be:

```
| a_count | b_count | c_count |
| ------- | ------- | ------- |
| 3       | 2       | 0       |
```

Answer (score 1):

should be able to do your pivot with case statements and not exists.

```
  SELECT Count (CASE
                    WHEN status = 'A' THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                  END) AS a_count,
           Count (CASE
                    WHEN status = 'B'
                         AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                         FROM   mytable b
                                         WHERE  a.KEY = b.KEY
                                                AND b.status = 'A') THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                  END) AS b_count,
           Count (CASE
                    WHEN status = 'C'
                         AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                         FROM   mytable c
                                         WHERE  a.KEY = c.KEY
                                                AND c.status IN ( 'A', 'B' )) THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                  END) AS c_count
    FROM   mytable a
```